# Can I use Microsoft App Center to log information such as what users are doing with a Xamarin Forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to log some basic information such as when my users change a setting on the application.  Is there a way that I can log this to Microsoft App Center?  I saw that there was some options but not sure if I can populate these from my application or how to go about doing it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are showing an App Center screenshot I'm going to assume that you have already initialized your app with the App Center code.

If not, you can find the instructions on the Overview page of your App Center app definition. In short, you should have these usings:

```
using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
```

and code similar to this:

```
AppCenter.Start("ios={Your iOS App secret here}" +
                  "uwp={Your UWP App secret here};" +
                  "android={Your Android App secret here}",
                  typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes))
```

In your `App.xaml.cs` `OnStart()` method.

You can take out crashes if you don't want to use it. It is Analytics we are after here.

Now, without doing anything special, you will automatically start retrieving details about your users. Which country are they in, what device they are using, what OS version and what version of your app to name a few.

If you want to identify custom events, like you state in your question, simply call something like this in the place that you want to track it:

`Analytics.TrackEvent("User changed a setting");` there is also an overload that allows you to specify some extra properties, like values that you might be interested in. You can do that like this:

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("Setting changed", new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "SettingName", "PushNotifications" },
    { "Value", "Off"}
});
```

Whenever the user passes one of these statements, the data will pop up in your App Center account.

More in-depth details can be found in the Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/appcenter/sdk/analytics/xamarin

Note: depending on what data you want to track and in which country you're in, etc. make sure that you understand local and international laws on gathering data. You might need to notify your users and allow them to opt-out. Be extra careful when you start collecting potentially sensitive or personal data.